# javascript run from web browser

Tags: javascript

i was wondering if you people could give me an example code for people to type in their address bar to automatically download something from a web address just by typing in that javascript line. Thanks

Comment: why do you need javascript? if you want people to download something (you should better explain us this 'something'), why don't you just provide the link to the resource itself?

Comment: You need to better explain or admins are going to shut you down fast and you're going to get down voted! hurry, and just describe what you need better

Answer (score 2):

Isn't that how [URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) work already?  Download something when you just type in the web address?

No JavaScript Needed!™

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna take a wild guess and assume your problem is that the file is opening in the browser, but instead you want it to be downloaded. That's not really a JS problem. You need to set/change the mime-type of whatever file you want people to download. **application/*_*_** usually works. **_** being the type of file. look here: http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp

There's also this other header which is sort of an extension of MIME you can add:

Content-disposition: attachment; filename=someFileName

More on that here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519

If it's something that's generated through php, you can throw this at the top:

More info would be useful so I supply you with a better example.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

`javascript:window.location.href=http://images.google.com/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&source=hp&biw=1482&bih=801&q=you+people%3F%21&gbv=2&aq=f&aqi=g3g-m7&aql=f&oq=`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need [BookMarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet).